# How is the PATH environment variable set in systemd user instance?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, path, systemd

With Ubuntu 21.04, GNOME 3.38.5 Wayland, and zsh as my shell,

`$ systemctl --user show-environment`

`PATH=/home/tony/.cargo/bin:/home/tony/.cargo/bin:/home/tony/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin`

I want to find out how `~/.cargo/bin` gets repeated three times, but can't find even one place where it is set.  `~/.pam_environment` didn't mention "PATH" at all, and I never run rust toolchain with `sudo` so it's unlikely that this variable is set in some files located in `/etc`.

How can I trace the setting of the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Please share the Linux distribution you're running (Ubuntu 20, etc.) and the shell type (bash, csh, etc.).

Comment: @ndemarco edited

Answer (score 11):

0. Before systemd --user starts, all PAM 'session' modules from `/etc/pam.d/systemd-user` are called.
1. When systemd --user starts, it runs a set of "[environment generators](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.environment-generator.html)" which
   are programs that output environment variables. They can be found in:

   - `/etc/systemd/user-environment-generators/`
   - `/usr/local/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/`
   - `/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/`
2. Systemd by default comes with just one such "environment generator", which reads simple KEY=value files from [environment.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html#) directories:

   - `~/.config/environment.d/*.conf`
   - `/etc/environment.d/*.conf`
   - `/run/environment.d/*.conf`
   - `/usr/lib/environment.d/*.conf`
   - `/etc/environment`
3. When your graphical session starts (whether using startx or a display manager), there is usually some script in the chain that calls `systemctl --user import-environment` and *copies* your $PATH and everything else from your interactive environment into the systemd environment.

   The same is also done by `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd`, which copies environment variables into a running 'dbus-daemon --session', but with the extra option it'll also update systemd.

   The same is also done natively by gnome-session, for a selection of environment variables (I'm not sure whether $PATH is one of them).

   The "import" tools might be called from:

   - `~/.xinitrc`
   - `~/.xsession`
   - `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh`

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `gnome-session` invokes the user's shell in non-interactive login mode, and the resulting environment is imported by systemd.

user1686's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1649689/441367) pointed me to the right direction: it might be `gnome-session`.  So I googled "gnome-session environment variables" and it seems that `gnome-session` invokes some shell and the environment is then imported into systemd.

In order to determine what actually happened, I did a couple of experiments by moving `export`s around, taking [this article](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e) as a reference.Turns out variables set in `~/.zshenv` or `~/.zprofile` will make their way into user systemd, but variables set in `~/.profile` and `~/.zshrc` will not.  It seems to be safe to conclude that your account's shell gets invoked as non-interactive login shell, and the environment is then imported by systemd.

What happened to my PATH was because the `export` appeared once in `.zshenv`, once in `.zprofile`, and once in `.profile` which my `.zprofile` sources.  As a solution, I recommend putting everything in `.profile` and make `.zprofile` source it.  This way works in both X and wayland.

Relevant [gnome bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736660); relevant [source](https://bug736660.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=343441) (yes, `gnome-session` is  shell script).